# GM vehicle - Saturn Aura Drivers Power Windows Malfunctioning

Tags: power-windows, saturn, aura

Looking for some suggestions to narrow the problem down.

My driver’s side window is working irregularly. The problem is strange, because when I pull the rubber conduit where the door joins with the body of the drivers side cabin, the window will work, but only until I open the drivers side door again. Somehow the wiring harnesses are getting pulled into making contact, and then not working afteward.

I pulled back the rubber cover and none of the wires appear broken or loose. The two ends seem to be plugged into each other, and following the cabin side there don’t appear to be any loose or broken wires.

Because the windows (drivers and both rear passenger) work flawlessly after I pull the harness/ connectors out, I’m thinking it’s a loose wire / connection issue and not a BCM/ ground issue? The front passenger window always works great ( I understand that one uses its own harness/ connection and is this unaffected).

Any suggestions for diagnoses?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do a pin drag test on the connectors. It’s possible a wire is breaking inside insulation. Next time without touching the door harness, pull the switch and figure out what is missing or load test the wiring.